# Saving a string with emojis in a file (python3)

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.5, emoji

I have a string like this one:

```
the_str = 'acuerda piolin usado dieron vez amigo secreto jajaja '
```

If I try to save it:

```
with open("some_name.txt", "a", encoding='UTF-8') as document:
    dociment.write(the_str)
```

I get an empty .txt file. How can I solve this? I tried to do the_str.encode('utf-8'), but the result is not a str but a bytes variable, and if I change "a" by "ab" then I get a `can't concat bytes to str` error.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried your code and it worked, change `dociment` to `document`

```
the_str = 'acuerda piolin usado dieron vez amigo secreto jajaja '
with open("some_name.txt", "a", encoding='utf-8') as document:
    document.write(the_str)
```

My output:
[image]

Comment: My code is a bit more complex, it was a typo when I was writing it. However it simplifies to what I wrote.

Comment: @VladimirVargas Write your complete code since with this piece of code I had no problem

Comment: I found the error. I have many sentences, if the sentence meets a condition then the sentence is written. However I first opened the file and then checked the condition, thus, creating a blank file. What I should do is to check the condition and then write the file. Sorry about that.

Comment: I have the same issue, but it's not from syntax. I'm sure that it is from codec, the error indicates: `UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u26d4' in position 4983: character maps to <undefined>`. any suggestion?

Comment: @Alireza try with `with open("some_name.txt", "a", encoding='utf-8') as document:`, 
Was the downvote necessary? :)

Comment: @eyllanesc sorry bro, both answers didn't work. but this encoding thing worked. will revert the downvote after 24h ;) pls fix your answer

Comment: @Alireza When you want to consult something you do not need the downvote, just comment. Do you think that by doing that you will encourage us to help you?